# moving boxes plugin callback function

Tags: javascript, jquery

this kind of emergency, so please, can someone help me...

I'm using movingboxes plugin for slideshow(this is the original plugin:http://css-tricks.com/moving-boxes/)
I need help with setting callback function add to the end of animation. I need to add fading effect, when `currentSlidecomplete` sliding,it should start  fading into another view of the same image, for example,`surrentSlide` src is `images/dr1.jpg` and i need it to fade to `images/dr1b.jpg` and come back to images/dr1.jpg. looping through each current Slide

something like
completed   :

```
function(e, slider, tar){

    //fading for each currentSlide goes here;//
  }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like you describe is already in the documentation

see the documentation here [1] and more specifically here [2].

EDIT: check jsfiddle here, i used a jquery add-on http://jsfiddle.net/r6yWC/157/
the add-on is here http://jqueryfordesigners.com/image-cross-fade-transition/
I also edited the code section below. I added the class "fade" to the img tag like this:

```
<img class="fade" src="http://chriscoyier.github.com/MovingBoxes/demo/4.jpg" alt="picture" style="background: url(http://chriscoyier.github.com/MovingBoxes/demo/2.jpg);"/>
```

In the 2nd link you will find a movingBoxes sample with a completed callback.

```
(function ($) {
    $.fn.cross = function (options) {
        return this.each(function (i) { 
            // cache the copy of jQuery(this) - the start image
            var $$ = $(this);

            // get the target from the backgroundImage + regexp
            var target = $$.css('backgroundImage').replace(/^url|[\(\)'"]/g, '');

            // nice long chain: wrap img element in span
            $$.wrap('<span style="position: relative;"></span>')
                // change selector to parent - i.e. newly created span
                .parent()
                // prepend a new image inside the span
                .prepend('<img>')
                // change the selector to the newly created image
                .find(':first-child')
                // set the image to the target
                .attr('src', target);

            // the CSS styling of the start image needs to be handled
            // differently for different browsers
            if ($.browser.msie || $.browser.mozilla) {
                $$.css({
                    'position' : 'absolute', 
                    'left' : 0,
                    'background' : '',
                    'top' : this.offsetTop
                });
            } else if ($.browser.opera && $.browser.version < 9.5) {
                // Browser sniffing is bad - however opera < 9.5 has a render bug 
                // so this is required to get around it we can't apply the 'top' : 0 
                // separately because Mozilla strips the style set originally somehow...                    
                $$.css({
                    'position' : 'absolute', 
                    'left' : 0,
                    'background' : '',
                    'top' : "0"
                });
            } else { // Safari
                $$.css({
                    'position' : 'absolute', 
                    'left' : 0,
                    'background' : ''
                });
            }

            // similar effect as single image technique, except using .animate 
            // which will handle the fading up from the right opacity for us
            $$.hover(function () {
                $$.stop().animate({
                    opacity: 0
                }, 250);
            }, function () {
                $$.stop().animate({
                    opacity: 1
                }, 250);
            });
        });
    };

})(jQuery);

$('#slider').movingBoxes({
// **** Appearance ****
// start with this panel
 ...
 ...

//-----> here is your callback
// callback after animation completes
completed: function(e, slider, tar){
    var img = slider.$panels.eq(tar).find('img');
    img.cross();
img.stop().animate({opacity: 0}, 1250).delay(500).animate({opacity: 1}, 2550);
}

});​
```

[1] https://github.com/chriscoyier/MovingBoxes/wiki

[2] http://jsfiddle.net/Mottie/r6yWC/2/

Comment: Thanks, I look at documentation already, not workingout for me, have to admit I'm new to this level of javascript and trying my hardest rto learn... Can you please give me an example on how I can add fading to that callback function? Please ?

Comment: Hi, I spend 3hours on this, really need to make it work. Can you look at the link, and guide me on what I'm doing wrong, please:http://jsfiddle.net/marb315/2SfVK/

Comment: not sure what you need to do, how is this http://pastebin.com/2jVwe7xg (all in one page, makes editing easier)

Comment: I need to fade current slide, one that on the middle and not on hover. How do I set it up to start with the current Slide?

Comment: Mirko, What I have now is fading "next" slide(on right side". I need to fade current one when page loads, and after that next, that slide in the middle... Can you help?

Comment: check my last pastbin link, the trick is to move the cross call to the function that also initializes the movingBoxes function ( $('#slider-two').movingBoxes ), once you do that you have access to all three slider images (last, current, next) in the complete function. simply copy the whole file, save it as html and run it in you browser. it fades the current to the alternative image and the two adjacent images back to their original

Comment: Mirko, now it's not returning to the original image-"front view" ... It has to end fading on the front view...

Comment: so, you want the currently selected image to fade to version b and back again? and the two to the left and to the right to remain in the original state?

Comment: http://pastebin.com/4CghhDep you can change the timing any way you wish by editing the delay and animation times

Comment: Mirko, can you please take a look at the page in IE. It looks like it's not showing default image at all...Only showing back view, no fading...

Comment: Ok, it works in IE 7 and 8 now.  if ($.browser.msie || $.browser.mozilla) {
                        $$.css({
                            'position' : 'absolute',
                            'left' : 0,
                            'background' : ''
                            //'top' : this.offsetTop//removed this
                        });